# Can I run my sink & disposal into my basement's sewage pump?

Tags: garbage-disposal, sewer

Can I run my sink & disposal into my basement's sewage pump?

My basement has a bathroom in it that uses an ejector pump. It works great.

Meanwhile, my kitchen sink & disposal are in the opposite corner from my sewer line to the city. The long travel distance causes it to get backed up. (The kitchen's sewer line is practical flat in various places.)

If I can safely run my kitchen line into the ejector pump, it should significantly reduce the tendency of my kitchen to get backed up - assuming the ejector pump itself can handle it.

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason why you can't run the kitchen drain into the basement bath ejector pump basin.  You will have to get the kitchen drain dumped into the ejector basin in a sanitary fashion.  The pump will cycle more often. You will probably shorten the life of the pump a bit.  If the pump is designed to handle the effluent from the basement bath it surely can handle a kitchen sink and dishwasher.
I would prefer this to a regular visit from the rooter man.

Comment: I agree no problems , you might want an alarm since running water upstairs may cause a problem if the pump fails.